# How do i paste my code in the python terminal using pyautogui?

Tags: python, variables, input, pyautogui

```
coin = input("coin: ")
pyautogui.click(button='right')
pyautogui.press('enter')
print(coin)
```

after the input came out, pyautogui cant run the next line which is right click to paste the code in terminal. Is there any other solution to paste my code and save it in a var?

Comment: Instead of

    pyautogui.click(button='right')

try using the same command I show here, which exists for better readability

    pyautogui.rightClick(x=moveToX, y=moveToY)

Moreover, I noticed from online examples that you need to move the mouse to the location where you want to click. Might it just be that you're not doing that, in your script?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you would be better of using the shortcut "ctrl + v" to paste it, like so:

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
```

However if your end goal is too get what is in your clipboard into a variable you could use this:

```
import win32clipboard

def getclipdata():
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
    return data
```

To use the function do this whenever you want the clipboard data in a variable:

```
clipdata = getclipdata()
```

I hope this helped, feel free to ask me any questions.

Comment: do i need to install the win32clipboard?

Comment: @newor0599 You may, using `pip install win32clipboard`, however it may come with python.